# Mysql скопировать значение по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите запрос, есть таблица:

```
product_id      lang        company_id      name
12345           ru          1               название 1
12345           ru          2               название 2
23345           ru          1               название 3
23345           ru          2               название 4
56567           ru          1               название 5
93990           ru          1               название 6
99992           ru          1               название 7
88289           ru          1               название 8
```

Нужно скопировать значение столбца name из company_id = 1 в company_id = 2 если product_id company_id 1 равен product_id company_id 2.

Comment: выбирайте данные по компании2, джйоните таблицу на себя же, но уже на компанию 1 и с тем же id, и апдейтите основную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример. Сначала, только для проверки, посмотрим как джойнится

```
select * from test t1 
inner join test t2 on t2.product_id=t1.product_id and t2.company_id<t1.company_id
```

Результат на приведенных данных:

| product_id | lang | company_id | name | product_id | lang | company_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ru | 2 | название 2 | 12345 | ru | 1 | название 1 |
| 23345 | ru | 2 | название 4 | 23345 | ru | 1 | название 3 |

Если все хорошо, делаем Update с тем же условием

```
update test t1 
inner join test t2 on t2.product_id=t1.product_id and t2.company_id<t1.company_id
  set  t1.name=t2.name;
```

Проверка **t2.company_id<t1.company_id** нужна для определенности, поскольку для строки product_id=12345 company_id=1 парой будет product_id=12345 company_id=2,
и для строки
product_id=12345 company_id=2 парой будет product_id=12345 company_id=1.
И какую апдейтить?
[Пример здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pk1Iyo-V)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!